# CSS ONLY based carousel - How make it correct (height?)

Tags: html, css

I found this CSS ONLY BASED fantastic carousel. Do you have an idea, how I can use it for a responsive design and showing 2 caroussels among each other?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZxjoX

```css
/* ***************************************************** */
/* SLIDER 1 */
/* ***************************************************** */

.carousel-wrapper {
 border: 1px solid red;
 background: red;
  position: relative;
  
}

.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80vh;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  background: url("../arrow.png") 50% 50%/20px no-repeat;
}

.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item .arrow.arrow-prev {
  left: 0;
}

.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item .arrow.arrow-next {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item.light {
  color: white;
}

.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item.light .arrow {
  background: url("../arrow.png") 50% 50%/20px no-repeat;
}

.carousel-wrapper [id^="target-item"] {
  display: none;
}

.carousel-wrapper .item-1 {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.carousel-wrapper .item-2 {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.carousel-wrapper .item-3 {
  background: url("../blurry.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-wrapper *:target ~ .item-1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.carousel-wrapper #target-item-1:target ~ .item-1 {
  border: 5px solid purple;
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-wrapper #target-item-2:target ~ .item-2, .carousel-wrapper #target-item-3:target ~ .item-3 {
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
  <span id="target-item-1"></span>
  <span id="target-item-2"></span>
  <span id="target-item-3"></span>
  <div class="carousel-item item-1">
    <p><br />x<br />x<br />x<br /></p>
    <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#target-item-3"></a>
    <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#target-item-2"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item item-2 light">
    <p><br />x<br />x<br />x<br /></p>
    <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#target-item-1"></a>
    <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#target-item-3"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item item-3">
    <p><br />x<br />x<br />x<br /></p>
    <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#target-item-2"></a>
    <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#target-item-1"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

original from: http://www.cssscript.com/pure-html-css-responsive-carousel-cari/

First problem is, that the height of the carousel can not be defined (i will use it afterwards with 100vw pictures instead of 
x
....).

Thank you so much,
Matthias

Comment: Your snippet doesn't even look like a carousel. What is this supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All slides have absolute positioning. Therefore carousel height is equal to zero.

However, slides are switched by the `z-index`, rather than `display`. Therefore, we can set `position: relative;` for the first slide of the carousel. Then its height will set the height of the entire carousel.

Check the code for two consecutive carousels:

```css
/* This code works for both carousels. */
.carousel-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;  /* fix the bug */
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  background: url("http://www.cssscript.com/demo/pure-html-css-responsive-carousel-cari/arrow.png") 50% 50%/20px no-repeat;
}
.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item .arrow.arrow-prev {
  left: 0;
}
.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item .arrow.arrow-next {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item.light {
  color: white;
}
.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item.light .arrow {
  background: url("../arrow.png") 50% 50%/20px no-repeat;
}
.carousel-wrapper [id^="target-item"] {
  display: none;
}

/* First carousel consists of slides No 1, 2 and 3. */
.carousel-wrapper .item-1 {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-wrapper *:target ~ .item-1 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-wrapper #target-item-1:target ~ .item-1 {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-wrapper #target-item-2:target ~ .item-2,
.carousel-wrapper #target-item-3:target ~ .item-3 {
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Second carousel consists of slides No 4, 5 and 6. */
.carousel-wrapper .item-4 {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-wrapper *:target ~ .item-4 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-wrapper #target-item-4:target ~ .item-4 {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-wrapper #target-item-5:target ~ .item-5,
.carousel-wrapper #target-item-6:target ~ .item-6 {
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Add a few lines to make design responsive. */
.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item > img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .carousel-wrapper .carousel-item .arrow,
  .carousel-wrapper .carousel-item.light .arrow {
    background-size: 10px;
    background-position: 10px 50%;
  }
}

/* Fix the height of carousel-wrapper. */
.carousel-wrapper .item-1,
.carousel-wrapper .item-4 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<h3>First carousel</h3>

<div class="carousel-wrapper">
  <span id="target-item-1"></span>
  <span id="target-item-2"></span>
  <span id="target-item-3"></span>
  <div class="carousel-item item-1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x650&text=Slide%20One" alt="Slide One">
    <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#target-item-3"></a>
    <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#target-item-2"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item item-2 light">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x650&text=Slide%20Two" alt="Slide Two">
    <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#target-item-1"></a>
    <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#target-item-3"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item item-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x650&text=Slide%20Three" alt="Slide Three">
    <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#target-item-2"></a>
    <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#target-item-1"></a>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Second carousel</h3>

<div class="carousel-wrapper">
  <span id="target-item-4"></span>
  <span id="target-item-5"></span>
  <span id="target-item-6"></span>
  <div class="carousel-item item-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x650&text=Slide%20Four" alt="Slide Four">
    <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#target-item-6"></a>
    <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#target-item-5"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item item-5 light">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x650&text=Slide%20Five" alt="Slide Five">
    <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#target-item-4"></a>
    <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#target-item-6"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item item-6">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x650&text=Slide%20Six" alt="Slide Six">
    <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#target-item-5"></a>
    <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#target-item-4"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/pyGQvW

Comment: THANK you so much Gleb !

Comment: What if I have in the css the code (img { margin: 0; float: left; })? The arrows don't work.... I need the img code because if not, there is always a white space between images listet among each other ...

Comment: Try to add `.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item > img { float: none; }`.